# React Router doesn't display sign in if there is user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a main routes component like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'

import AdminPanel from './pages/AdminPanel/AdminPanel'
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn'

import '../assets/stylesheets/styles.scss'

const AppContent = props => <Router>
  <div>
    <PrivateRoute path='/' component={AdminPanel} />
    <Route path='/sign-in' component={SignIn} />
  </div>
</Router>

export default AppContent
```

Here is the `PrivateRoute.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'

import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, currentUser, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      currentUser ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/sign-in',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
)

export default connect(({ currentUser }) => ({ currentUser }))(PrivateRoute)
```

so if `currentUser` is null it redirects to `/sign-in` which is perfectly fine. However the problem is if there is `currentUser` and I go to `/sign-in` I still get the `AdminPanel` component.

Here is the `currentUser` reducer and `AdminPanel` component in case needed.

```
import { SIGNIN, SIGNOUT } from '../actions/types'

// so here the default state is null, however if I change it to `{}` which will mean there is a user then I am not able to go to the `/sign-in`
export default (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNIN:
      return action.payload
    case SIGNOUT:
      return null
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And `AdminPanel`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Box, { Container } from 'react-layout-components'

import LeftMenu from '../../components/AdminPanel/LeftMenu'
import Header from '../../components/AdminPanel/Header'

import Home from './Home'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import Categories from './Categories'
import Partners from './Partners'
import Users from './Users'
import TeamMembers from './TeamMembers'
import Settings from './Settings'
import Help from './Help'

class AdminPanel extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Box>
        <Container minWidth={300}>
          <LeftMenu />
        </Container>
        <Container padding='15px' width='100%'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path='/categories' component={Categories} />
            <Route exact path='/partners' component={Partners} />
            <Route exact path='/users' component={Users} />
            <Route exact path='/team-members' component={TeamMembers} />
            <Route exact path='/settings' component={Settings} />
            <Route exact path='/help' component={Help} />
          </Switch>
          <Header />
        </Container>
      </Box>
    )
  }
}

export default AdminPanel
```

And `SignIn` component is just a plain class based component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SignIn extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>SignIn</div>
    )
  }
}

export default SignIn
```

Comment: "However the problem is if there is currentUser and I go to /sign-in I still get the AdminPanel component."  How is your SignIn component? It is weird you are getting AdminPanel going to /sign-in since there is a route for SignIn component. Is there any redirect?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what props and rest are in that instance.

Comment: @devserkan it is just a class based component with a div in it. Nothing more for now. You can see it in the edited question.

Comment: @JayJordan SignIn just gets props from react-router, `history`, `location` and `match`

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that if you have no currentUser it goes to sign in, but if there is a currentUser it directs you to admin panel? Where should it direct you instead?

Comment: @HaykSafaryan, your /sign-in route is a regular one. In your question you are saying if there is currentUser /sign-in goes to AdminPanel. How is this possible? Your /sign-in route must render SignIn component without question. I am confused. If you mean "/" here, did you try `exact` prop for your "/" route in the AppContent? Since without exact route will always hit / first, then if there is currentUser it goes to AdminPanel.

Comment: @devserkan adding `exact` both to `/` and `/sign-in` almost solves the issue. Now if I go to `/` it renders `AdminPanel` with `Home` component in it. However if I go `/dashboard` I get `AdminPanel` with `Home` again instead of `Dashboard`

Comment: @JayJordan problem is if there is current user and I go to `/sign-in` I get `AdminPanel` again.

Comment: @HaykSafaryan, first, you don't need `exact` for sign-in. Because there is not any sub path belong to it. But, you need `exact` again in your AdminPanel's first route which is `/`. So, only `/` hits Home, other sub paths like Dashboard render their component successfully. If you skip `exact` there always `/` is being hit and you will always see Home component, not Dashboard with `/dashboard`. Just look at the React Router documentation a little bit more :)

Comment: Oh, I see now you have `exact` for every route in AdminPanel. You don't need those but with this setup actually it should work. Let us see what will happen when you clean up all those `exact`s other than `/`.

Comment: @devserkan I remove `exact` from everywhere, I only now have `<PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={AdminPanel} />` in `AppContent` and in `AdminPanel` I have `<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />` and still `AdminPanel` renders `Home` only. Also I noticed if I open new browser tab and go to any path like `/dashboard` nothing is rendered.

Comment: Ok, I think I also need to study React Router a little bit more :) I'm not quite sure we can use multiple `/` routes in the same app like that. If possible I want to learn, too. If you want to hide all your components under `/` path, you can use something like that maybe: https://codesandbox.io/s/wyz4r3v03w There is no Home, `/` redirects to AdminPanel. But if you want a component named Home, then just rename AdminPanel to Home, since there is no public Home in your component. Note that, I'm passing currentUser as boolean in PrivateRoute. You can test it changing to false.

Comment: One other possible logic is having a public Home, something like landing page if no currentUser. Then, if user logs in redirect it to something like /dashboard. After that use paths like /dashboard/categories, /dashboard/partners etc. With that logic you can have one PrivateRoute and in the /dashboard component you can setup other Routes.